# Need an algorithm for 3D vectors intersection

Tags: vector, 3d, geometry, line, intersection

I have 2 vectors, each defined by 2 `Point3D` (origin and direction). I need to find out the point of their intersection.
A little bit of help is always welcome.
I will post my function, which gives me wrong output.

```
public static CurvIntersect3D Intersect2Linii3D (Vector3D dr1, Vector3D dr2) {
    CurvIntersect3D result = new CurvIntersect3D(0, null);

    double x = Math3D.VectorNorm3D(dr1.getDirectie());
    double t = Math3D.VectorNorm3D(dr2.getDirectie());
    double cosa = (dr1.getDirectie().getX()*dr2.getDirectie().getX() + dr1.getDirectie().getY()*dr2.getDirectie().getY() + dr1.getDirectie().getZ()*dr2.getDirectie().getZ()) / (t*x);
    Punct3D p1 = dr1.getOrigine();
    Punct3D p2 = new Punct3D(), p3 = new Punct3D();
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        p2.set(i, dr1.getOrigine().get(i) + dr1.getDirectie().get(i));
        p3.set(i, dr1.getOrigine().get(i) + dr2.getDirectie().get(i));
    }

    Matrici.Matrice3x3 rot = Math3D.GetMatriceRotatie(p1, p2, p3);
    Punct3D orig = new Punct3D();
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        orig.set(i, rot.getElement(i, 0) * (dr2.getOrigine().getX()-dr1.getOrigine().getX()) +
                    rot.getElement(i, 1) * (dr2.getOrigine().getY()-dr1.getOrigine().getY()) +
                    rot.getElement(i, 2) * (dr2.getOrigine().getZ()-dr1.getOrigine().getZ()));

    x = orig.getY() - orig.getZ()* cosa / Math.sqrt(1 - cosa*cosa);
    p1 = new Punct3D();
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        p1.set(i, dr1.getOrigine().get(i) + x*dr1.getDirectie().get(i));
    result.setCount(1);
    result.add(p1);
    return result;
}
```

CurvIntersec3D is a structure that stores the array of points and its length.

Comment: By specifying an origin and direction and are specifying a line and not a vector.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned before the two lines may not meet at a single point. The best you can do in general is find the point on line1 closest to line2 and vise versa. Connect those two points to create the *common normal* direction.

Given two lines passing through 3D points `r1=[r1x,r1y,r1z]` and `r2=[r2x,r2y,r2z]` and having unit directions `e1=[e1x,e1y,e1z]` and `e2=[e2x,e2y,e2z]` you can find the points on the line which are closest to the other line like this:

1. Find the direction projection `u=Dot(e1,e2)=e1x*e2x+e1y*e2y+e1z*e2z`
2. If `u==1` then lines are parallel. No intersection exists.
3. Find the separation projections `t1=Dot(r2-r1,e1)` and `t2=Dot(r2-r1,e2)`
4. Find distance along line1 `d1 = (t1-u*t2)/(1-u*u)`
5. Find distance along line2 `d2 = (t2-u*t1)/(u*u-1)`
6. Find the point on line1 `p1=Add(r1,Scale(d1,e1))`
7. Find the point on line2 `p2=Add(r2,Scale(d2,e2))`

Note: You must have the directions as unit vectors, `Dot(e1,e1)=1` and `Dot(e2,e2)=1`. 
The function `Dot()` is the vector dot product. The function `Add()` adds the components of vectors, and the function `Scale()` multiplies the components of the vector with a number.

Good luck.

Comment: Good catch, when `u==1` the lines are parallel. I corrected the post.

Comment: Two parallel lines going in the opposites directions will give `u==-1`. Also a case to avoid division by zero.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your lines have intersection?

If it is guaranteed, then the problem is rather simple: Get parametric equations of lines, solve a system of two linear equations like these:

A_X0+t*A_Dir_X = B_X0+u*B_DirX , where X0 is base point, and Dir is direction vector (take into account any pair of coordinates with non-zero cross product)

If not, then it is necessary to calculate a distance between two [skew lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines) at first. If the distance is zero, then we could find intersection point.